# How do you solve an algebraic equation over a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have the following equation:
$$n^2-n+1=0$$

Where $n$ is an element of a ring over elements $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$, and addition and multiplication are defined modularly (e.g. $2+1=-2$). How would you go about solving this equation over a ring?

Comment: Your ring is finite (five elements). A very quick way is to check all the possibilities. In sharp contrast to high school your teacher has absolutely no business questioning that approach :-) You may not find very many solutions though :-(

Comment: There is no such thing as "defined modularly" unless you know what value of $m$ you are using in $\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z.$ If you really have 5 elements then it would be reasonable to say $m=5.$ If they are not distinct, I might expect $m=3$ was intended, especially for this polynomial. What is your multiplication table? What is $2 \cdot 2?$

Comment: @WillJagy Forgive me, as I am not experienced in abstract algebra, so I did not know the proper terminology. I believe most understood what I was trying to get across. $2\cdot{2}=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your ring is finite, you can always manually check which $n$ satisfy the equation, by plugging them in. Five cases are manageable.

---

If you are familiar with the ring, you are talking about, then you might know, that the ring is actually a field - *the* field with five elements $\mathbb F_5$. Here, you can use your standard techniques to solve a quadratic equation

(For convenience, we don't restrict ourselves to $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$, but allow all integers as *symbols*. Note, that different symbols might denote the same element, e. g. $-3=2=7$)

Now, let's *complete the square* as usual:

$$n^2-n+1=n^2-n+\frac14+\frac34=\left(n-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac34=(n-3)^2+2 $$
(As always, the fractional notation $\frac1a$ denotes the multiplicative inverse  of $a$. In finite fields, they can be calculated using the Euclidean Algorithm, but in this case you can find them by hand: 
$$\frac12=3, \quad \frac34=3\cdot\frac14=3\cdot 4=2$$
Now, this justifies the last equation)

So, it follows, that 
$$(n-3)^2=3$$
When using this method in $\mathbb R$, you would check if the sign of the right-hand side. If it were negative, you would stop, since there were no solutions, if it was positive you would get two equations (one for each root) and if it was zero, then $0$ would be the only root.

In arbitrary fields, this is similar, the only root of $0$ is $0$, other elements have either none or two roots. However, in general, the field is not ordered, so there is no simple criterion to decide whether roots exist.

In this case, we check, that
$$0^2=0,\; 1^2=1,\; 2^2=4,\; 3^2=4,\; 4^2=1$$
so $3$ has no roots and the equation has no solutions.

Comment: It might be clearer to write $(n+2)^2+2$, since, as the question is written, $3$ isn't an element of the ring.

Comment: Yes, but then I would need to replace $\frac14$ etc. too, and then you might loose the idea of what is happening. If the OP is not familiar with this notation and the idea of finite fields, then my answer is not the right way and he should better go by Jyrkis answer. I wanted to give an idea, how this can be solved in general.